# sending email through hidden .onionservice for email

Tags: email

assuming all emails sent to the clearnet from a specific email provider are tracked by country e.g. all emails from protonmail will have a link to switzerland and the NSA AI will scan and read them cause they are in the clearnet. If protonmail uses a .onion address, does the email exit protonmail servers into the clearnet through a tor exit node? Can the NSA AI track it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should slice it into two parts:

### Client to server communication

If you want to access the server to send or receive an email, you can use tor and access the hidden service. This has the advantage that an attacker under normal circumstances is unable to see that you have connected with your IP to the server.

### Server to server communication

If the server sends an email to another server it uses the clearnet under *normal circumstances*. The clearnet is used to avoid these emails being marked as spam at the receiving server because almost every tor exit node is on spam blacklists.

## Summary

Protonmail mails are not send through an exit node. Because of that the NSA might track that the mail is sent from switzerland.

## Small Overview

**Client_A ---(tor)---> ProtonMail ------> MailProvider_B -----> Client_B**

**Legend:**

---(tor)-->: Connection via tor

---------->: Clearnet connection, which hopefully uses TLS

## Encrypted & meta-data-free alternatives

The following alternatives are relatively new and might have vulnerabilities:

- BitMessage(Alpha)
- Tox
- ZeroNet Mail(https://zeronet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_zeronet/sample_sites/#zeromail)

Comment: In Essence it can also track that its a protonmail email

Comment: yep, you are right. But it should not be able to track the email sender and receiver if TLS connections are used for the clearnet communication.... On the other hand you should know that in most countries email providers hand out the emails of an user if asked by the law enforcement...

Comment: How then does one send email that cant be tracked by the NSA

Comment: Use Tor for anonymization and encryption(e.g. OpenPGP) to hide the content of the email. This actually results in pseudonymization and should be enough in most countries. The law enforcement then only knows that two persons have communicated with each other, but do not know who these persons are and what they talked about...

Comment: What if the other recipient does not use OpenPGP.  The sender uses Scryptmail and or protonmail.  Sender sends to random people but does not want his email snooped.  Powerful adversary knows sender already uses Scryptmail or protonmail. Sende moved from Gmail to these but adversary knows now

Comment: There is no solution if the recipient refuses to use encryption. If you think a perfect solution could be possible you should have a look at the following xkcd comic: https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58569/discussion-between-securitydude5-and-nebulak).

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted answer if it answers your question, because it takes time and effort to answer questions. I have also added alternatives to protonmail/email...